# Regular expression to pick extension

Tags: c++, regex, qt

What would regular expression look like for any string which ends with .txt?
Tried few myself but it doesn't look like I'm getting anywhere.

I'd like to construct a regex object to feed a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like : `.*\.txt$`
If you want more precisions, I guess you should precise a language and some other stuffs...

Comment: hi, I'm programming in C++ with Qt.

Comment: `\.txt$` would be enough or no regex at all, if the language has something equivalent to `str.endsWith('.txt')` or even a filepath parser which can extract the extension.

Comment: depends on what you want to match I guess, and +1 for the edited part

Comment: @Mog I have to pass a regex obj to my fnc.

Comment: I proposed an edit of your question that should allow you to get more answers, I'm no C++ fan so I can't help you with this part :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Perl-style regular expressions, /[^\.]*\.txt$/ should work.

Comment: I'm getting unknown escape character \.

Comment: In languages such as C and C++, you probably need to use \\ instead of \

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is match the end of the string using

```
/\.txt$/
```

Matching more than that e.g., `.*\.txt$` is not necessary